# How to install latest Discord

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade

I'm on Arch Linux. I have Discord version 0.0.13-1 installed. I launched the app and got a message saying v0.0.14 is available. Usually I just run `yay -Syu` to upgrade `discord` package. But even after that, the latest version installed i still 0.0.13.

How do I update Discord?

Comment: You can get it at https://discord.com/new/download. My guess is that an Archlinux package of the newest version doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from here : https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/discord/ (on the right, download from mirror)

Then in your download folder : `sudo pacman -U discord-0.0.14-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst`

Comment: Why does this happen?

Answer (score -3):

There is a simple solution for that. Just go to `/opt/discord/resources` and there you'll find a file called `build_info.json`.
Open this file using any text editor like "vim" or "nano". On that file change the version to the version that Discord is saying to install. As for your case, on that file the version will be `0.0.13`. All you have to do is change the version to `0.0.14`.

Now save and exit the file. And you also have to open the file with sudo access. After that try to open discord and there will be no issue like that.

Comment: Even though I hate discord for being proprietary crap, I can see that this is a very bad solution.

Comment: Also, this solution is *bad* -- at *best* what this would accomplish is that the local client wold mis-report its version information, which *might* be enough to connect to remote servers, right up until said servers send a response the old client doesn't know what to do with.